# Returning a function vs setting a const equal to a function in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to React and was wondering why I'm getting a `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render` error.

In my code there is an existing:

```
const SomeConst = SomeFunctionThatReturnsAComponent();
```

Now I am trying to update that const to have some logic before calling the function like so:

```
const SomeConst = (props) => {
   //Some logic
   return (SomeFunctionThatReturnsAComponent()());
}
```

Here is SomeFunctionThatReturnsAComponent():

```
const Template = component => (props) => {
   const ReturnThisComponent = props => <Component component={component}, {props} />

   return ReturnThisComponent;
}
```

The usage of `SomeConst` remains the same as the original implementation:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {

   return (<SomeConst prop1="foo"/>)
}
```

I am wondering why this is not functionally the same thing and why I am getting this error. I have not been able to find a post that gets this error with the way I have it implemented. They are different implementations that arrive at this same error so they were not that much of a help to me.

If there is another post, I would kindly ask to link me to it and I will quickly remove this post and link it to the other post for future people.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything, I have tried to create this post as a repex.

Comment: Please post `SomeFunctionThatReturnsAComponent` code.

Comment: You are missing one function call. `SomeFunctionThatReturnsAComponent()()`

Comment: @kinduser, that was it! I'm trying to understand that function call a little bit more, what does each parentheses do? I think the first one calls the initial function but what does the second one do?

Comment: Added an extended answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - you are missing one function call.

```
SomeFunctionThatReturnsAComponent()();
```

> what does each parentheses do?

The first parens are calling the first function, that returns a function that returns `ReturnThisComponent`. If you call this function (`Template`) only once, you will still return a function `(props) => { ... };`

```
const Template = component => (props) => {
  const ReturnThisComponent = props => <Component component={component}, {props} />

  return ReturnThisComponent;
}
```

So either - call the function twice, or - remove the second *curried* function `(props) =>` (and I think this is what you wanted to achieve). So it will look like:

```
const Template = (component) => {
  const Component = component;

  const ReturnThisComponent = (props) => <Component {...props} />;

  return ReturnThisComponent;
}
```